# Sql query confusion

Tags: sql

I'm stumped on a sql query.

In a query, I have a result set like so:

```
FooId      Name     Value       SourceLevel  SourceId    RecordId
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  1       'Foo'      10               1           0          1
  1       'Foo'      25               3           1          2
  2       'Bar'      33               1           0          3
```

To that query, I pass parameters @Level1Level, @Level2Level, @Level3Level, and @Level1Id, @Level2Id, @Level3Id

(no, these aren't real names, but they illustrate my point).

My query is trying to do a filter like this:

```
WHERE ((SourceLevel = @Level1Level AND SourceId = @Level1Id)
OR (SourceLevel = @Level2Level AND SourceId = @Level2Id)
OR (SourceLevel = @Level3Level AND SourceId = @Level3Id))
```

If I pass in parameters like so:

```
@Level1Level = 1, @Level2Level = 2, @Level3Level = 3
@Level1Id = 0, @Level2Id = 3, @Level3Id = 2
```

I would want recordIds 1 and 3 back.

But, if I pass in parameters like so:

```
@Level1Level = 1, @Level2Level = 2, @Level3Level = 3
@Level1Id = 0, @Level2Id = 3, @Level3Id = 1
```

I would want recordIds 2 and 3 back. Unfortunately, in the second case, I'm getting all 3 records back, which makes sense, because of the OR in my where clause. I can't figure out how to limit my result set to say "only choose SourceLevel 1 if I haven't already matched on SourceLevel 2 or 3".

Anyone have any thoughts, assuming this makes any sense?

To clarify: I want each FooId from my result set, but only the most specific FooId available, based on the SourceLevel parameters passed in.

Comment: Is your sample data correct? You have the same values for 'SourceLevel' & 'SourceId' for the first and third rows.

Comment: Yes, they're different FooIds...I want each FooId in the result, but only the most specific one based on the SourceLevel.

Comment: I understand but the SourceLevel and SourceID for RecordID 1 & 3 are exactly the same. If you are using SourceLevel and SourceID to differentiate you will always get both rows. See also the answer from Bugai13, he's mapped out the possible combinations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
WHERE 
(
  (SourceLevel = @Level3Level AND SourceId = @Level3Id)
  OR
  (
    SourceLevel = @Level2Level AND SourceId = @Level2Id
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM SourceTable WHERE SourceLevel = @Level3Level And SourceId = @Level3Id AND FooId = SourceTable.FooId)
  )
  OR
  (
    SourceLevel = @Level1Level AND SourceId = @Level1Id
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM SourceTable WHERE SourceLevel = @Level3Level And SourceId = @Level3Id AND FooId = SourceTable.FooId)
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM SourceTable WHERE SourceLevel = @Level2Level And SourceId = @Level2Id AND FooId = SourceTable.FooId)
  )
)
```

This seems to do the filtering I was after...sorry that the question was so confusing. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(SourceLevel = 1 AND SourceId = 0) match 1 and 3 records
(SourceLevel = 2 AND SourceId = 3) no matches
(SourceLevel = 3 AND SourceId = 1) match 2 record
```

All three records will be returned by the query.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see exactly the point and why it's a sql question. But if you want SourceLevel 1 (i call it SL1 now) only if you haven't yet SL2 or SL3...

why don't you try with this:

SL2 OR SL3 OR (NOT SL2 AND NOT SL3 AND SL1)